# How to return a query set in get_queryset() in Django

Tags: django

I'm currently trying to convert my FBV codes to CBV. `get_context_data` is working well by returning contexts that I put in. However, `get_queryset()` returns NOTHING for some reason. To double-check, I tried to print `search_stores` right before returning it and it printed the queryset that is supposed to be printed. However, when I printed it on Django template, by typing {{ search_stores }}, it shows nothing. Am I using `get_queryset` in a wrong way?

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'boutique/search.html'
    # paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_text'] = self.request.GET.get('search_text')
        context['sorter'] = self.request.GET.get('sorter')
        if not context['sorter']:
            context['sorter'] = 'popularity'
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):

        search_text = self.request.GET.get('search_text')
        sorter = self.request.GET.get('sorter')

        if search_text:
            search_stores = Store.objects.filter(Q(businessName__icontains=search_text) | Q(mKey__icontains=search_text))
            if sorter == 'businessName':
                search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter)
            else:
                search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter).reverse()
        else:
            search_stores = ''

        for store in search_stores:
            store.mKey = store.mKey.split(' ')

        print(search_stores)
        return search_stores
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queryset is accessible via the `context_object_name`. 
By default it's `object_list` if you don't provide `context_object_name`
You can access the queryset in `templates` with `object_list`

If you want to change the name, change the `context_object_name`:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
   model = Store
   template_name = 'boutique/search.html'
   context_object_name = 'search_stores'
```

`search_stores` will be the variable accessible to loop through in templates

Comment: glad to be of help!

Comment: I just have a minor question. Is it possible to return multiple query sets in `get_queryset()`?

Comment: `get_queryset` is only for the Model belongs to the CBV, if you want to send multiple queryset, you can do so in `get_context_data()`

Comment: ok then if I wanna use pagination on a specific queryset, that queryset must be returned from `get_queryset`. Is that correct?